# Should you impute missing event and time-to-event variables for survival data that has missing and censored data?

Tags: survival, multiple-imputation

I am working on a database that looks at progression-free survival and includes event and time-to-event data. It is missing about 40% of both time-to-event data and event data. I am wondering if I should impute the missing event and time-to-event data, or simply exclude them from the analysis? Would it make sense to exclude missing event and time-to-event data and impute other missing data (other covariates have about 10% missing data)? I am using multiple imputation with chained equations. You can see some example code below:

````
library('mice')

set.seed(1234) # Set seed for reproducibility

# Create time variable ranging from 1 month to 5 years
time <- sort(runif(500, 1, 60))

# Create event variable with 50% probability of event occurrence
event <- rbinom(500, 1, 0.5)

# Create treatment variable with 50% probability of treatment occurrence
treatment <- rbinom(500, 1, 0.5)

# Create grade variable with 80% of treated patients having 'high' grade disease
grade_treated <- sample(c("low", "high"), sum(treatment), prob = c(0.2, 0.8), replace = TRUE)
grade_untreated <- sample(c("low", "high"), sum(1-treatment), prob = c(0.5, 0.5), replace = TRUE)
grade <- factor(c(grade_treated, grade_untreated))

# Create missing data for time, event, and grade variables
time[sample(500, 200)] <- NA
event[sample(500, 200)] <- NA
grade[sample(500, 50)] <- NA

# Combine variables into a data frame
dat <- data.frame(event, time, treatment, grade)

#Run MICE
dat$event <- as.factor(dat$event);
dat$treatment <- as.factor(dat$treatment);
dat$grade <- as.factor(dat$grade);

dat_imp <- mice(dat, maxit=5, print=FALSE);
```
````

Comment: I’d question the missing at random assumption here, and the suitability of this observational dataset for answering a question in a reliable way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking for. If you're asking whether the outcome data should be included when imputing covariates: If the substantive models (e.g., Cox model) will include outcome, treatment and covariates, at least all of them should also be included in the imputation model for congeniality. In `mice`, for time-to-event data, it is recommended that you transform them to cumulative hazard using `mice::nelsonaalen`.

If you're asking whether you should impute missing events in your outcome variable, you typically don't need to. For time-to-event analysis, you'll typically have last event-free data for patients that you can use to create a censoring indicator, and under assumptions of uninformative censoring, use it for your substantive models without needing to impute any outcomes.